# Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time #472

Tags: installation, appium

I am new to Appium and I am trying to run the appium.app with iOS option using stimulator.I have selected the app path and show stimulator log with platform version as 8.1.

I have also added appium.txt file with the following content in the appium installation directory.
    [caps]
    platformName = "ios"
    deviceName = "iPhone 6"
    platformVersion = "8.1"
    app = “/Users/dhanasekarbabu/downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app"

Also please find the following log,

```
    Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "/Users/dhanasekarbabu/Downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app" --show-ios-log --default-device

    info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.6 (REV 004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e)

    info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
    info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/dhanasekarbabu/Downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.1","defaultDevice":true,"showIOSLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200}
    info: Console LogLevel: debug

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}

    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 13.582 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 4.070 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
    info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 1.517 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}

    info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium"}}

    error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName

    info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/720.2.4 Darwin/14.1.0 (x86_64)
    info: [debug] Got configuration error, not starting session
    info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
    info: [debug] Error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName
    at Capabilities.checkValidity (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/capabilities.js:143:13)
    at Appium.configure (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:238:35)
    at null. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:118:10)
    at Appium.start (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:129:5)
    at Object.exports.createSession as handle
    at next_layer (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:113:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:117:5)
    at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:222:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:288:12)
    at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:19)
    info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName)","origValue":"The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName"},"sessionId":null}
    info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 16.616 ms - 286

    error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.698 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
```

Also if i select force device and provided a UDID after selecting the UDID I'm getting the issue "Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time".
I have changed the stuimulator devices and i am facing the same issue.

Also please find the following go for your reference.

```
    Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "/Users/dhanasekarbabu/Downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app" --udid "F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB" --show-ios-log --device-name "iPhone 5 (F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB)"

    info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.6 (REV 004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e)

    info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
    info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/dhanasekarbabu/Downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app","udid":"F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB","deviceName":"iPhone 5 (F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB)","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.1","showIOSLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200}

    info: Console LogLevel: debug

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}

    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 12.528 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 4.022 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"}}}
    info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}
    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 1.527 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}

    info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone 5 (F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB)"}}

    info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/720.2.4 Darwin/14.1.0 (x86_64)

    info: [debug] Using local app from command line: /Users/dhanasekarbabu/Downloads/untitled/UICatalog.app

    info: [debug] Creating new appium session 8a4d5f38-d574-4338-85e3-443e04a26ed8
    info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
    info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
    info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
    info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

    info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

    info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

    info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.2

    info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

    info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
    info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
    info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings
    info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app
    info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)

    info: [debug] Creating instruments
    info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
    info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/dhanasekarbabu/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
    info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
    ...
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/dhanasekarbabu/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-2911698fabce8e2c.js

    info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/dhanasekarbabu/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-2911698fabce8e2c.js
    info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.2","iOSSDKVersion":"8.2","deviceName":"iPhone 5 (F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB)","platformVersion":"8.1"}
    info: [debug] fixDevice is on
    info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 5 (F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB) (8.1 Simulator)'
    info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
    info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
    info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
    info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
    info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

    info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state

    info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
    info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
    info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole

    info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

    info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"8a4d5f38-d574-4338-85e3-443e04a26ed8"}
    info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.968 ms - 178 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"8a4d5f38-d574-4338-85e3-443e04a26ed8"}

    info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

    info: [debug] Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time
    at null._onTimeout (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios-log.js:137:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)

    error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time

    info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time)","origValue":"Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time"},"sessionId":null}
    info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 10325.771 ms - 234 
    info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
    info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB
    info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id F07654AE-E9B5-4A5F-956A-D20091413DAB --bundle com.example.apple-samplecode.UICatalog

    error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Log capture did not start in a reasonable amount of time
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance

```
    Regards,
    Rajesh D
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?